# reading a csv file and store it in a linked list ( in java )

Tags: java, csv

I have a big csv file , contains a graph 
each line of this csv is a edge of graph ( for example 1,23 means there is a edge between 1 and 23 )
Im going to read this csv formatted text file and store the graph in a linked list

what is the best way?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
String SEPARATOR = ",";
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("/path/to/your/file"));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] fields = line.split(SEPARATOR, -1);
        List<String> field = new LinkedList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
                field.add(fields[i]);
            System.out.println(field);
}
```